# AngularJS filter already selected options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have 3 selects that all share the same options. As an option is selected in one of them, I want to filter it out of the other selects.

I took a stab at it here and did not have any luck.
http://plnkr.co/edit/ERGTbQSjoX3IpGAomcUn?p=preview

```
<select name="ques1" ng-model="q1" required>
    <option value="">question</option>
    <option ng-repeat="question in questions | filter: { Id : '!' + q2 } | filter: { Id : '!' + q3 }" value="{{ question.Id }}">{{ question.Question }}</option>
</select>
```

Any advice? And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally make it work. According to the [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). You can pass a function as argument to the filter. So I created a function that returns a function which will be passed to filter:

```
  $scope.negative = function(){
    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) 

     return function(value ,index, array){
       var scope = $scope;

       for(var i = 0 ; i<arr.length ;i++) {
          if(value.Id == scope[arr[i]]) return false;
       }

       return true;

     }
  }
```

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/k1Qq0rWBqCcXeFcodvBQ?p=preview)

Comment: While your approach did work @jme11, my scenario allows the user to start with any select they choose. That was a detail I did not think to include.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly got it:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.q1 = '';
  $scope.q2 = '';
  $scope.q3 = '';
    
  $scope.questions = [
    { Id: 1, Question: '1 Question' },
    { Id: 2, Question: '2 Question' },
    { Id: 3, Question: '3 Question' },
    { Id: 4, Question: '4 Question' },
    { Id: 5, Question: '5 Question' }
  ]; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="form" novalidate>
    <div>
      <select name="ques1" ng-model="q1" required>
        <option value="">question</option>
        <option ng-repeat="question in questions" value="{{ question.Id }}">{{ question.Question }}</option>
      </select>
      <p class="error" ng-show="form.ques1.$error.required && form.ques1.$touched">question is required</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select name="ques2" ng-model="q2" required>
        <option value="">question</option>
        <option ng-repeat="question in questions | filter: ({Id: '!' + q1})" value="{{ question.Id }}">{{ question.Question }}</option>
      </select>
      <p class="error" ng-show="form.ques2.$error.required && form.ques2.$touched">question is required</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select name="ques3" ng-model="q3" required>
        <option value="">question</option>
        <option ng-repeat="question in questions | filter: ({ Id : '!' + q1 }) | filter: ({ Id : '!' + q2 })" value="{{ question.Id }}">{{ question.Question }}</option>
      </select>
      <p class="error" ng-show="form.ques3.$error.required && form.ques3.$touched">question is required</p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first and second select do not filter out the selection of third select. Say, if your third select picks '3 Question', the first select should not contain the option '3 Question' any more.

Comment: So your assumption is that someone will pick from the third select first? Hmmm interesting UX assumption.  I'm not saying your wrong, I just assumed you were doing this for selecting security questions.  I wouldn't expect that behavior based on that usage and I would lock in the question/answer pairs immediately in that case.  Anyway, glad you got the solution you wanted.  Best of luck.