# filter ng-options for selected

Tags: angularjs, filter, selected, angularjs-ng-options

i have a dynamic number of ng-options which is added on click
i want to remove the selected option from a ng-option

```
<select  ng-model="obj.name"   ng-options="selectFromObj.name as (selectFromObj|filterSelected) for selectFromObj in selectFromObjs" >
</select>
```

i created a filter for that

```
app.filter('filterSelected', function() {
   return function(itm) {
       for (var i = 0;   i < var1.length; i++) {

       if(var1[i].name != null){
        if ( var1[i].name == itm.name ) {

          itm.splice(i,1);
        }
       }
  }
});
```

can you give me ideas on what should i do here ?
should i loop for my input objects via my selected objects and compare them and then push i tried that put i came up with much cases i should handle .
I want to splice any choice form a select tag in the other dynamic added tags
cant i check easily if selected just doesn't return it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS filter already selected options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440322/angularjs-filter-already-selected-options)

Comment: thanks for mention sir after many tries it works :) with the help of the answer  also i changed my idea :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you could just use something like this:

```
filter: {selectFromObj.name:obj.name}
```

Comment: i want to splice the already chosen options in the newly added select tags thanks for  answer